# onesignal : how can I get my user id phone among hundreds of registered users?

Tags: onesignal

I have published my first onesignal application.

Problem is : I cannot find my phone among hundreds of registered users so I can send some test notifications without having to spam all my users : **how can I determine my user id ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the best way to do this is to open your app and then sort the user list by last active time and try to spot your device near the top.

OneSignal is working on making this process a bit easier in the future.